# Proving a tensor product has dimension 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Can u guys help me prove that $$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3+y,x^2+y) \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Q}[x,y]} \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-y)$$has dimension 2 as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm not having good ideas about it, thanks.

Comment: Did you compute the dimension of the two spaces on each side of the tensor product? Dimension is multiplicative for tensor products.

Comment: No i did not, i only knew that worked for free modules. But yeah that makes sense.

Comment: @quarague This were true if you would tensor over a field, here the tensor product is over a commutative ring which is not a field. Clearly in this question the right tensor factor is infinite dimensional, so there is nothing to gain just computing the dimension.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3+y,x^2+y) \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Q}[x,y]} \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-y)=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^3+y,x^2+y,x^2-y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use that for a commutative ring $R$ you have $R/I\otimes_R R/J\cong R/(I+J)$, see e.g. [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388361/15416).

Then try to find a basis of $R/(I+J)$ by using the conditions in $I+J$. Further hint: In $R/(I+J)$ you have $x^2=y$ and $x^2=-y$. What does that say about $y$?

Comment: Yeah thats my biggest problem , is identifying the elements in $R/(I+J)$

Comment: @PedroSantos I provided a further hint to get you started.

Comment: The class of $y$ and $x^2$ are going to be zero , so thats why i get the 2 dimension vector space ? cause an element will be of the form $ax+b$?

Comment: @PedroSantos Yes, exactly (for a complete answer you also have to prove that the residue classes of $1$ and $x$ are linearly independent in the quotient).