# Show that $R/I\otimes_R R/J \cong R/(I+J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

> Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring and $I$, $J$ $\lhd$ $R$ two 2-sided ideals of $R$. Show that 
>   $$R/I\otimes_RR/J\cong R/(I+J)$$

I need to define a isomorphism between, but I didn't understand how I show the well-define, surjectivity, and homomorphism. Can you help me please.
There is a similar question but there is no commutative condition in here. And I guess there also should need to show that it is a homomorphism.
[Show that $R/I\otimes_R R/J\cong R/(I+J)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388361/show-that-r-i-otimes-r-r-j-cong-r-ij)

Comment: The claim in the title (and first quote block) is not the same as in the link at bottom of the body of your Question.  That is, a tensor product is not the same construction as a direct product.  For the proposition in the title, did you consider simple cases such as when $I=J$?

Comment: I am sorry for that, it should be a tensor product. Thank for that.

Comment: I added a few words at the outset to emphasize your interest in the non-commutative case.  Please review and rollback the edit if I've unintentionally changed your meaning.

Comment: If you really are interested in the non-commutative case, you might find this [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091423/tensor-product-of-modules-over-non-commutative-rings) and its Accepted Answer helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x\otimes y \mapsto xy$ ?

There are some things to be said here :

- you need to check that it is well-defined. For this, you'll first have to show that it is well-defined on $R/I\times R/J\to R/(I+J)$.  You can then use the universal property of the tensor product.
- You need to check that it is a map of the type you want (i.e. a group morphism, or an $(R,R)$-bimodule morphism, or an $R$-module morphism, depending on the precise claim you're making)
- Surjectivity should be easy.
- Then you probably want to define an inverse. For this it will help to prove that $I+J$ annihilates $1\otimes 1$ in $(R/I)\otimes_R (R/J)$ (on either side, here noncommutativity won't change much, because we're dealing with such simple modules, and because our ideals are two-sided)