# Tensor product of two quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules, tensor-products

I am trying to compute $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\otimes_{k[x,y]} k[x,y]/(y)$ as a $k[x,y]$-module, where $k$ is a field. I know that $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\cong k[x]$ and $k[x,y]/(y)\cong k[x]$ as rings, and that $k[x]\otimes_k k[x] \cong k[x,y]$, so I expect the answer is $k[x,y]$, but I cannot obtain an isomorphism (need not be explicit) between $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\otimes_{k[x,y]} k[x,y]/(y)$ and $k[x,y]$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388361/show-that-r-i-otimes-r-r-j-cong-r-ij) (or a good exercise) that

$$R/I \otimes_R R/J \cong R/(I+J)$$

by the map $(r + I) \otimes (s + J) \mapsto rs + (I+J)$, extended linearly.

Then in your case, we get an isomorphism

$$k[x,y] \big / (y-x^2) \otimes k[x,y] \big / (y) \cong k[x,y] \big / (y-x^2, y)$$

do you see how to finish the computation from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see that $k[x,y]/(y-x^2,y)=k[x,y]/(x^2,y)$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$ as rings, but $k[x]/(x^2)$ is not a $k[x,y]$-module so should I end the computation by $k[x,y]/(x^2,y)$?

Comment: $k[x]/x^2$ is a $k[x,y]$ module where $y \cdot p = 0$ for every $p$! Otherwise you're exactly right ^_^. Also, I can't help but mention: Notice this ring is $2$ dimensional over $k$, which corresponds to the fact that the intersection of $y-x^2$ and $y$ has multiplicity $2$.